# Create an instance of a class per constructor parameter value with application lifetime

Tags: c#, ninject

I have

```
class Sender : ISender
{
    public Sender(string queueName)
    { ...
    }
}
```

I want only one instance of class Sender with a given queueName. This instance should be the same and not be disposed while the application is running.

I can use code like

```
ISender testSender = 
    Kernel.Get<ISender>(new ConstructorArgument("queueName", "Test"));
```

to get a reference to the sender instance with queueName = "Test"

What ninject binding can I use to implement this?

I tried

```
Kernel.Bind<ISender>().To<BufferedMessageSender>()
    .InScope(c => 
      c.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "queueName").GetValue(c, null));
```

but it does not work.

Comment: According to me the rewrite of nemesv did the trick :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [InSingletonScope](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes).